# Why only LocalLDAModel on spark1.5 has the function of topic prediction?

Tags: apache-spark, prediction, lda

I want to use the trained LDA model to predict the topics of documents.Why only LocalLDAModel on spark1.5 has the method of topicDistributions()? And how can i use spark2.0,spark2.1 or spark2.3 to predict document's topics?

Comment: All versions of Spark (since version 1.3.0) should have the `topicDistributions` method for `LocalLDAModel`. Where are you looking? The Scala docs have it at least: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LocalLDAModel

Comment: thanks,i found it in org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.package, which does not conclude topicDistributions